# Do the different ethereum clients (geth, parity, etc) behave as equal peers to one another?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

Do clients differentiate their peers based upon what language they are implemented in or do they all work together without discrimination?

For example does a geth node seek out other geth nodes? ...or will it just as easily use a parity node to sync with?

If it doesn’t discriminate, are the nodes even aware of what the peer client is written in?  Or from that level of interaction are they “blind” to that info?